# Post a status to Twitter with only Login+Pass

Tags: curl, twitter

I deeply expect that I can post a status to Twitter without having to create and App with write permission!

So, in *the old days* people could only use basic auth with user:password. I want some equivalent for it.

Ideally, it is some **curl** snippet that input **username**, **pass**, **message**(just text, nothing fancy), and the output is that it posts my update to twitter.
If the status post fail for some reason, no problem.

**EDIT**: It is entirely OK if there are 2 or more requests to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, can't do that anymore. Sorry.

Comment: see my EDIT, still same answer? :(

Comment: Yup. Its very difficult to do what you're saying securely.

Comment: @FabianoPS yes. You still have to register an application etc.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will do as described and use ntwitter fo Node.js. Still, I feel a bit outraged as developer that cannot be a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As has been explained, you cannot simply pas along a user's details.  This is to protect the user's security.

You may be interested in [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth) - that way you can take a username & password & exchange it for oAuth tokens.

Comment: Thanks for raising the option!